# Django MIgrations Issues

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-migrations

I'm facing Django migrations problems for a very long time and used to solve that problem using the `--fake` keyword but then I realized that it's not a good approach and even creates more problems, so after that whenever I faced that issue so I remove the DB and recreate it and then applied migrations and it was working fine but now our data is important and can't remove the DB. The problem is I've created a new Django app in my project and generated the migrations and applied them and working fine at the local but it throws the error I attached below related to migrations. I tried to apply them using the `--fake` keyword because the feature needs to be at that time but again it was not working I checked the migrations using `python manage.py showmigrations` and the migrations is there but when I checked `django_migrations` table in my DB and not a single migration file of that app is not found there, what's the best solution to overcome this issue?

`error`:

```
ProgrammingError at ....

column .... does not exist
```

`python manage.py migrate kanban_board zero`

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: 
column "project_id" of relation "kanban_board" does not exist
```

`latest migration of kanban_board app where I added project relation`:

```
from django.db import migrations, models
import django.db.models.deletion


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('projects', '0005_alter_project_options'),
        ('kanban_board', '0003_auto_20220425_1252'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='kanbanboard',
            name='project',
            field=models.ForeignKey(null=True, on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='projects.project'),
        ),
    ]
```

Comment: yes. `--fake` does not create DB tables. That is exactly how it is supposed to work. The root cause of your problem is that you where unable to add the migration from your new feature in the first place. I would suggest to undo your fake migrations again (with `--fake`) and then look at fixing the root issue. What errors are you getting?

Comment: How did you end up using `--fake` regularly (What migration workflow do you follow)? It only meant to be used if you are manually applying some changes or fixing some problems with the migrations. Ideally when you use `--fake` you should be confident that you know _exactly_ what you are doing.

Comment: @ErikKalkoken I'm trying to reverse all migrations of that app but getting the same errors when I was applying that migrations, updated the answer please have a look

Comment: you have to migrate zero with `--fake`

Comment: @ErikKalkoken done, but when applying again getting error `django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "kanban_board" already exists`